# Spring, @Aspect, @AfterThrowing, blank screen response

Tags: java, spring, aspectj

1. I have aspectjrt-1.5.4.jar, aspectjweaver-1.6.1.jar, org.springframework.aop-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar in my applications classpath.
2. My applicationContext.xml contains

   ```
   <aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>
   <bean id="loggerAspect" class="com.company.logging.LoggerAspect" />
   ```
3. My LoggerAspect.java contains

   ```
   @Aspect
   public class LoggerAspect
   {

       @Before("execution( * com.company..*(..)) and !execution( * com.company.*.action..*(..))")
       public void logEntry(JoinPoint joinPoint)
       {
           Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(joinPoint.getTarget().getClass());
           String className = joinPoint.getTarget().getClass().getCanonicalName();
           logger.debug(className + " :: " + joinPoint.getSignature().getName() + " :: " + "Entry");
       }

       @AfterReturning("execution( * com.company..*(..)) and !execution( * com.company.*.action..*(..))")
       public void logExit(JoinPoint joinPoint)
       {
           Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(joinPoint.getTarget().getClass());
           String className = joinPoint.getTarget().getClass().getCanonicalName();
           logger.debug(className + " :: " + joinPoint.getSignature().getName() + " :: " + "Exit");
       }


       @AfterThrowing(pointcut = "execution(* com.company..*(..))", throwing = "throwable")
           public void logException(Throwable throwable)
       {
           System.out.println(throwable.getMessage());
       }

   }
   ```
4. If i comment the logException pointcut, everything else works just fine.
      And entry and exit logs are generated.
      However if i uncomment it, the below exception occurs.
5. I am getting an error as

> java.lang.NullPointerException
>         org.apache.struts2.convention.ConventionUnknownHandler.handleUnknownActionMethod(ConventionUnknownHandler.java:412)
>         com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultUnknownHandlerManager.handleUnknownMethod(DefaultUnknownHandlerManager.java:102)
>         com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:439)
>         com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:291)
>         com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:254)
>         com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:133)
>         com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
>         com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:207)
>         com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
>         com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
>         com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:207)
>         com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
>         com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
>         org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:75)
>         com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
>         org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:94)
>         com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
>         com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:166)
>         com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
>         com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
>         org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
>         com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
>         com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:187)
>         com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
>         org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:52)
>         org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:485)
>         org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
>         org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:91)
>         org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:368)
>         org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:109)
>         org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
>         org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
>         org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:97)
>         org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
>         org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:100)
>         org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
>         org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:78)
>         org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
>         org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
>         org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
>         org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:35)
>         org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
>         org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:177)
>         org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
>         org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:187)
>         org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
>         org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
>         org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
>         org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:79)
>         org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
>         org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter.doFilter(ConcurrentSessionFilter.java:109)
>         org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
>         org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:169)
>         org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
>         org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)

6.
i did the following changes

- Used aspectjweaver-1.6.10.jar. And removed the two old jars.
- Made the change as proposed by Oleg. (which was actually a silly mistake on my part). 
  I have updated the logException method above with the latest that i am using.

I am not getting the above particular error anymore. However now as soon as my first struts action of the application (home.action) is called, the response is a blank screen.

If my logException method has pointcut = "execution(* com.company1..*(..))"
where company1 is not a valid package of my project, things work fine.
But if i have it as pointcut = "execution(* com.company..*(..))"
where company is a  valid package of my project, i get a blank response to every struts action

Comment: Thanks Sean for correctly formatting my post. I tried my best, but just couldn't get it right with some of the code formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying to apply advice to Struts actions which are not Spring beans. I modified the method as below and it started working.

```
@AfterThrowing(pointcut = "execution( * com.company..*(..)) and !execution( * com.company.*.action..*(..))", throwing = "throwable")
public void logException(JoinPoint joinPoint,Throwable throwable)
{
    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(joinPoint.getTarget().getClass());
    String className = joinPoint.getTarget().getClass().getCanonicalName();
    logger.error(className + " :: " + joinPoint.getSignature().getName() + " :: " + "Exception", throwable);
}
```

Keeping the above in mind, i wonder if its always a bad idea to use `* com.company..*(..)`.
And rather keep it specific by applying on specific packages such as service, business, data access etc.

Answer (score 1):

"I have aspectjrt-1.5.4.jar, aspectjweaver-1.6.1.jar" could be your problem. Besides being potentially incompatible to each other, they are very old versions. You should upgrade to 1.6.10 version of aspectjweaver and drop aspectjrt--aspectjweaver includes all classes in it already.

Comment: i am increasingly liking stack overflow. i mean if you have somebody like Ramnivas Laddad answering your very first query on AspectJ, what else can you ask for.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know correct definition of pointcut should looks like this

```
@AfterThrowing(pointcut = "execution(* com.company..*(..))", throwing = "exception")
public void logException(Throwable exception)
{
    System.out.println(exception.getMessage());
}
```

Please pay attention that *throwing* should contain name of parameter you're binding in the method itself (*exception* in this case).

While I don't see how it relates to exception you're getting this might be the root cause.

Comment: I would try the suggestions provided and come back in an hour or so with the update.